# Get Regex occurance with escaped symbols

Tags: c#, regex

I would appreciate help with non-working regex (does not work for special symbols % or $)

```
    public System.Tuple<string, string> GetParts(string str, string beginMark, string endMark)
    {
        var pattern =
            new Regex(beginMark + @"(?<val>.*?)" + endMark,
                RegexOptions.Compiled |
                RegexOptions.Singleline);

        return (from Match match in pattern.Matches(str)
                where match.Success
                select new Tuple(
                    match.Value,
                    match.Groups["val"].Value))
               .ToList();
    }
```

Calling method:

```
string input = @"%sometext%\another text";
string replacedValue = "AAA";
var occurrences = GetPart(input, @"(%", ")");
foreach (var occurrence in occurrences)
{
    Console.WriteLine(occurrence.Item1 + Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine(occurrence.Item2 + Environment.NewLine);
    // replace
    onsole.WriteLine(input.Replace(occurrence.Item1, replacedValue) + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Expected Output:

%sometext%

sometext

AAA\another text

Comment: So you want to get three expected output ?

Comment: Yes, it's kind of parsing Environment variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your symbols. Try to change

```
new Regex(beginMark + @"(?<val>.*?)" + endMark,
```

to

```
new Regex(Regex.Escape(beginMark) + @"(?<val>.*?)" + Regex.Escape(endMark),
```